# Cannot resolve method registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter) in Fragment class

Tags: java, android

```
//here my code
//used this IntentFilter

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

//this method cannot be resolve

registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do that in Fragment:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 4):

`registerReceiver` is the method found in `Context` class. `Fragment` does not extend it, but the `Activity` does. That's why you can use it like this:

```
registerReceiver.(receiver, filter);
```

In the activity, but you must call it on a context from the Fragment either like this:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Or even better in `onAttach`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
      context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```